# "such intention" vs. "such an intention"

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

"Intention" is a countable word, so I think we should say:

> Trainers intend to help the participants, or they are employed based on
>   such **an** intention.

But the word has been frequently used without "an". For example see [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=such%20intention%2Csuch%20an%20intention&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuch%20intention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuch%20an%20intention%3B%2Cc0)

Is there any clear rule about using "a/an" for countable words?

Comment: Did you look at the results below the graph? The actual "examples" taken from Google books?

Answer (score 4):

Most English dictionaries tell us that *Intent* is uncountable, and *intention* is countable. As your ngram demonstrates, though, it is not uncommon to see *intention* used where *intent* would serve, but without the article (or other determiner) we might properly expect. *Such* is a determiner in English, but only when used with a plural ("such intentions") or uncountable ("such intent") noun.

It is interesting that many (if not most) of the examples of *"such intention"*  returned by the ngram are found in books that treat of jurisprudence. This may be a manifestation of the peculiar trait of writing in the fields of science, medicine, and the law, that the articles are often omitted where "good grammar" or syntax would require them.

It may also be due to the tendency of such writing to preserve archaic constructions.
This use of *intention* as an uncountable noun certainly has a long history in English;

> 1601   B. Jonson *Fountaine of Selfe-love* i. v. sig. C4v   My Soule (Like one that lookes on ill affected eyes) Is hurt with meere Intention on their follies.
>
> 1749   G. Lavington *Enthusiasm Methodists & Papists: Pt. II* 54   Disease, caused perhaps by..deep Intention of Thought.
>
> 1791   J. Boswell *Life Johnson* anno 1752 I. 134   [At one time, Johnson said to Beauclerk] You never open your mouth but with intention to give pain.

There *is* a clear rule: Countable, singular nouns must have a *determiner*, but that determiner need not be an article:

- They had *every* intention of landing at Gatwick.
- *His* intention was to keep walking.
- What is *your* intention toward this maiden?
- *Dave's* intention was to catch the ball.